# Maximize select width in table when having a label

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, jquery-select2

This looks like one of those things that should have a simple answer, however I could not find any solution for it...

I have a table that contains several *select* elements, which have some text labels in front, on the same line.
I want to maximize the width of the *select* until the end of the *td* element.
I cannot use fixed widths.

If I use width=100% then the select will push the label out on a different line. By default, the *select* width is equal to the width of the longest *option*.

Here is how the default works: http://goo.gl/KiSGcK

Ideally, this should work with select2 also, where the default width is set to the width of the first *option*.

I have tried wrapping the *select* and/or the label in *divs*, setting different css options (float, display inline, etc) with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried with 99% or less %?

Comment: Why can't you just use select {width: 60%} in your css?

Comment: Because the text can be larger than 40%, and in any case if the text is less than 40% the select will not get to the end of the td, i.e. if the text is 20%, there will be 20% empty space after select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution: use `overflow: hidden`.

Here it is: http://goo.gl/mXNRZN

Answer (score 0):

Try to set float: left; for your label and table also. Then set them with width in percent that total is 100%. Like this label(width:40%) and table(width:60% except the border).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I cannot assume the text width will be less than 40%. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/LeAgK/ the last label is on 2 lines, but if you take 60% out from the css it will be on 1 line....